# Click items in an ng-repeat to fill another list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a working plunker where you select a thing from a dropdown and it displays data. I would like to be able to click one of those items and it to fill another list below. with other data. I know of `ng-click` and thats what I am using currently to just pop up an alert with the data I want to be in the list.

This is the section in question:

```
  <div>
    <select ng-options="post as post.id for post in allPosts" ng-model="selectPost" ng-change="select()">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()" />
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in records | orderBy:'email':reverse" ng-click="moreInfo(item)">
        {{item.email}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Ideally I want a list like what is in the popup something like:

```
Email: 'email...'
Name: 'name...'
Body: 'body...'
```

Like what is in the popup, but to show up below the list of things displayed from choosing the dropdown. (on my webpage it will be over to the right so I am not concerned about formatting, just how to do it). But I **DO NOT** want the the list to show up if I don't click on an option.

[Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0O8YVKEkGWOXU7mAI4PH?p=preview)

**edit:** I am beginning to think maybe an `ng-show` will do the trick in some fashion, yet, I still do not know how I would pass the data down to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `div` that will be visible when a `message` variable is available.

```
<div ng-show="message">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

and in your controller, assign the contents for the `moreInfo` to a `$scope.message`:

```
$scope.moreInfo = function(id) {
  $scope.message = "Email: " + id.email + "\nName: " + id.name + "\nBody: " + id.body;
};
```

Here's an updated **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ys8uCBAowuQWzEiDoGDR?p=preview)**.

Comment: Well you provided a plunker and i like it the best, so now YOU WIN! :) Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

I edited your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/snILNvwIrENowpdCPS5c?p=preview) , hope that is what you wanted.. and it's better for you to use `controller as` syntax [article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) and you should looki into styleguide too i like this one by John Papa [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: Consider posting some of the code you changed, explaining what needed to be done to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite straightforward:

First, set your new text to a scope value on click:

```
$scope.moreInfo = function(id) {
    $scope.curResults = "Email: " + id.email + "\nName: " + id.name + "\nBody: " + id.body
    //alert("Email: " + id.email + "\nName: " + id.name + "\nBody: " + id.body);
};
```

Then, simply assign this value to another div:

```
<div ng-show="curResults">{{curResults}}</div>
```

Then, whenever you click on the results, `curResults` is updated and shown in that div.

`ng-show="curResults"` makes sure the div is only shown when there's a value set to `curResults`.